# how to get afterFeature and afterScenario report in either karate or cucumber reporting

Tags: karate

Is it possible to see the status of the calls in a afterFeature and afterScenario as a report inside of either cucumber-html-reporting and the karate reports (preferably both)

Regards

Comment: just edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check again. I thought `afterScenario` is already being logged. Honestly you should use the `after` hooks only in rare circumstances.  <strike>But feel free to raise a feature request for the `afterFeature` to be present in the logs as well.</strike>

EDIT: Actually just realized that *only* if you use a `*.feature` file to implement your afterScenario and afterFeature hooks - will you see the logs. I just tested this [(see commit)](https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/4e4583390f28891665033607ace88272f4ab6aff). So you have to use `karate.call('my-hook-code.feature')` in the hook JS.

So yes, if you print anything in JavaScript or use `karate.log()` it will *not* appear in the report. This is intentional, the reporting is tuned to work only for feature steps.