# karate.log(args) on afterScenario hook is not embedded on surefire json file

Tags: karate

I am doing `karate.log(...args)` on my hook file. It is printed on the `karate.log` and the console.

However I do not find the log on the .json file generated by surefire, which leads to the log does not appear on my html report.

[image]

Is there any steps I am missing here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes hooks don't log to the HTML report, sorry. Are you doing testing or just worrying about reports :)

Comment: Ah I see. Haha, I am just trying to make the error stands out whenever there is one :))

Comment: I found an answer of yours here. Will put it as reference for others who are looking for the same thing. Thanks again Peter! :)) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578395/how-to-get-afterfeature-and-afterscenario-report-in-either-karate-or-cucumber-re

Comment: @Raymond there is a chance that some of the fixes in the `develop` branch will make this also work, if you can build from source, do test it ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide